# How to specify a list of values ​in a form in which CheckboxSelectMultiple is used?

Tags: django

I have a problem with the form in django. It uses the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget, but I need to set a list of possible choices only for posts created by the currently logged in user.

Any idea?

form:

```py
class CycleForm(BSModalForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cycle
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'posts']
        widgets = {
            'posts': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

models

```py
class Cycle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="Brak opisu")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    content = MDTextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numbers_of_entries = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views

```py
class CycleCreateView(BSModalCreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'blog/cycle_form.html'
    form_class = CycleForm

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        reverse_user = self.request.user
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': reverse_user})


class CycleUpdateView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Cycle
    template_name = 'blog/cycle_update.html'
    form_class = CycleForm
    success_message = 'Success: Cycle was updated.'

    def get_success_url(self):
        reverse_user = self.request.user
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': reverse_user})
```

Comment: Can you share the `Post` model, and your view where you use this form?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can slightly alter the `CycleForm` form and add a `user` parameter. If that parameter is set, we filter the `queryset` of the `posts` field by only using `Post`s

```
class CycleForm(BSModalForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['posts'].queryset = Post.objects.filter(author=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Cycle
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'posts']
        widgets = {
            'posts': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

Now we only need to pass the `user` to the form, we can override the [**`get_form_kwargs`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs):

```
class CycleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'blog/cycle_form.html'
    form_class = CycleForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(user=self.request.user)
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        reverse_user = self.request.user
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': reverse_user})
```

You should do the same with the `UpdateView`. Note that your `LoginRequiredMixin` likely should be put first in the base classes.

Comment: I got this error:

self.field['posts'].queryset = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
AttributeError: 'CycleForm' object has no attribute 'field'

Comment: @Pilaverci: sorry that's a typo: it is `fields`, not `field`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked! By the way, I have a question, how can I extract data from this form? I mean doing something like the title of the cycle as a headline and under it the titles of individual posts that belong to this cycle

Comment: That's in `form.cleaned_data['title']`. You can access that in `form_valid` (not before, since first the form needs to be validated first).

Comment: sorry but i'm quite new to django and i'm self-taught so i don't know exactly what you mean, could you give me the piece of code you're talking about?

Comment: @Pilaverci: in your `def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):` method, you can retrieve the title with `title = form.cleaned_data['title']`.

Comment: okay, but if I understand it correctly, this solution works only if I have `def form_valid` in the view, and what if I would like to use it in another view that does not have this function?

Comment: @Pilaverci: no, this has nothing to do with filtering, and if your form is a `ModelForm`, you do not have to save the data yourself. The `CreateView` and `UpdateView` will handle that for you. You can obtain the data from a form after you called `form.is_valid()` (and that returned `True`) through the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary. By using a `CreateView` or `UpdateView`, you do not need to write that "boilerplate" code.

Comment: but I meant a completely different view, e.g. `def profile (request):` which has nothing to do with formulas, and only has to display data from the database, it will also work?

Comment: @Pilaverci: if the data is stored in the database, you need to retrieve it through a query, so by constructing querysets. The `CreateView`/`UpdateView` will create/update records in the database. You can not inspect a form you used in a previous view. Note that HTTP is a stateless protocol.